# ASP.NET Core Razor Pages - Disable all the buttons on multiple forms

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I’m working on ASP.NET Core Razor Pages
and I'm trying to disable all the buttons on the page when a button is clicked.
My code looks something like this:

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="DisableBtns()">
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="btn1" > </button>
</form>


<form method="post" onsubmit="DisableBtns()">
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="btn2" > </button>
</form>


<script>
    function DisableBtns() {
        alert("The form was submitted");
        btn1.disabled = true; btn2.disabled = true; return true;
    }
</script>
```

My problem is the alert did execute but the buttons are not disabled.

The following code does work but I don't want it I want to use the function way:

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="btn1.disabled = true; btn2.disabled = true; return true;">
</form>
```

Can someone please help me resolve this issue or if you have a better way that works on Razor Pages I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unsure whether you have declare `btn1` and `btn2` variables as you didn't show them.

**Solution 1: With JavaScript [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp)**

```js
function DisableBtns() {
    alert("The form was submitted");

    document.querySelectorAll("form button").forEach(x => {
        x.disabled = true;
    });
        
    return true;
}
```

---

**Solution 2: With jQuery**

Pre-requisite:

You have imported jQuery library.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
function DisableBtns() {
    alert("The form was submitted");
    
    $("form button").prop('disabled', true);
        
    return true;
}
```

Comment: both of your solutions worked fine but I prefer the JavaScript one, thanks for the help

Comment: can you not do this with c# or .net?

Comment: Hi @Bigbob23, I don't think you can use C# code to disable the button during form submission. Unless you are using Blazor.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to remove `onsubmit` and use `$("form button[type='submit']").click()`,here is a demo:

form:

```
<form method="post">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="btn1"> </button>
</form>


<form method="post">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="btn2"> </button>
</form>
```

js:

```
$("form button[type='submit']").click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("form button[type='submit']").each(function(index) {
                $(this).attr("disabled",true);
            });
        })
```